# How to efficiently transform wide-format patient information data into time series of patient counts?

Tags: r, optimization

**Data**

Given the following data frame where each row represents information on a single patient

- `DateStart` contains the date of admission to the hospital of the individual patient
- `DateEnd` contains the day of hospital discharge of the individual patient
- `Length` is just the difference of `DateEnd` and `DateStart`

| DateStart | DateEnd | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-02 | 2020-04-10 | 39 days |
| 2020-03-30 | 2020-04-09 | 10 days |
| 2020-03-15 | 2020-03-28 | 13 days |
| 2020-06-02 | 2020-06-20 | 18 days |

and I basically want to transform this into a time series of counts of patients per day kinda like the sample below

| Days | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-02 | 1 |
| 2020-03-03 | 1 |
| 2020-03-04 | 1 |
| 2020-03-05 | 1 |
| 2020-03-06 | 1 |
| 2020-03-07 | 1 |
| 2020-03-08 | 1 |
| 2020-03-09 | 1 |
| 2020-03-10 | 1 |
| 2020-03-11 | 1 |

**Problem**
The issue is that the one I made to solve this is kinda slow, `CaseCountGenerator()`, and I wonder if there is a more efficient approach.

my working code is as follows

```
library(tidyverse)
createDays=function(start,end){
  Days=seq.Date(from=start,to=end,by=1)
  return(Days)
}

CaseCountGenerator=function(Starts,Ends,Length,Days){
  Counts=rep(0,length(Days))
  
  for(j in 1:length(Starts)){
    
    for(l in 1:length(Days)){
      
      if(Days[l]==Starts[j]){
        for(m in ((1:Length[j])-1)){
          Counts[l+m]=Counts[l+m]+1
        }
        break
      }
      
      
    }
  }
  
  return(Counts)
}
```

a sample data

```
tempdf = structure(list(DateStart = structure(c(18323, 18351, 18336, 18415, 
18417, 18418, 18428, 18439, 18439, 18438, 18440, 18439, 18444, 
18451, 18444, 18452, 18444, 18445, 18450, 18452), tzone = "Asia/Manila", class = "Date"), 
DateEnd = structure(c(18362, 18361, 18349, 18433, 18470, 
18460, 18447, 18460, 18458, 18458, 18459, 18459, 18472, 18463, 
18464, 18464, 18458, 18464, 18472, 18470), tzone = "Asia/Manila", class = "Date"), 
Length = structure(c(39, 10, 13, 18, 53, 42, 19, 21, 19, 
20, 19, 20, 28, 12, 20, 12, 14, 19, 22, 18), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and how it all works

```
Days=createDays(min(tempdf$DateStart),
                max(tempdf$DateEnd))
  
Counts=CaseCountGenerator(tempdf$DateStart,
                          tempdf$DateEnd,
                          tempdf$Length,
                          Days)
  
result=tibble(Days,Counts)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't test the speed but here is a base R option with `outer` + `rowSums` that you can try

```
with(tempdf, {
  d <- seq(min(DateStart), max(DateEnd), by = "day")
  cnt <- rowSums(outer(d, DateStart, `>=`) & outer(d, DateEnd, `<=`))
  data.frame(date = d, counts = cnt)
})
```

which gives

```
          date counts
1   2020-03-02      1
2   2020-03-03      1
3   2020-03-04      1
4   2020-03-05      1
5   2020-03-06      1
6   2020-03-07      1
7   2020-03-08      1
8   2020-03-09      1
9   2020-03-10      1
10  2020-03-11      1
11  2020-03-12      1
12  2020-03-13      1
13  2020-03-14      1
14  2020-03-15      2
15  2020-03-16      2
16  2020-03-17      2
17  2020-03-18      2
18  2020-03-19      2
19  2020-03-20      2
20  2020-03-21      2
21  2020-03-22      2
22  2020-03-23      2
23  2020-03-24      2
24  2020-03-25      2
25  2020-03-26      2
26  2020-03-27      2
27  2020-03-28      2
28  2020-03-29      1
29  2020-03-30      2
30  2020-03-31      2
31  2020-04-01      2
32  2020-04-02      2
33  2020-04-03      2
34  2020-04-04      2
35  2020-04-05      2
36  2020-04-06      2
37  2020-04-07      2
38  2020-04-08      2
39  2020-04-09      2
40  2020-04-10      1
41  2020-04-11      0
42  2020-04-12      0
43  2020-04-13      0
44  2020-04-14      0
45  2020-04-15      0
46  2020-04-16      0
47  2020-04-17      0
48  2020-04-18      0
49  2020-04-19      0
50  2020-04-20      0
51  2020-04-21      0
52  2020-04-22      0
53  2020-04-23      0
54  2020-04-24      0
55  2020-04-25      0
56  2020-04-26      0
57  2020-04-27      0
58  2020-04-28      0
59  2020-04-29      0
60  2020-04-30      0
61  2020-05-01      0
62  2020-05-02      0
63  2020-05-03      0
64  2020-05-04      0
65  2020-05-05      0
66  2020-05-06      0
67  2020-05-07      0
68  2020-05-08      0
69  2020-05-09      0
70  2020-05-10      0
71  2020-05-11      0
72  2020-05-12      0
73  2020-05-13      0
74  2020-05-14      0
75  2020-05-15      0
76  2020-05-16      0
77  2020-05-17      0
78  2020-05-18      0
79  2020-05-19      0
80  2020-05-20      0
81  2020-05-21      0
82  2020-05-22      0
83  2020-05-23      0
84  2020-05-24      0
85  2020-05-25      0
86  2020-05-26      0
87  2020-05-27      0
88  2020-05-28      0
89  2020-05-29      0
90  2020-05-30      0
91  2020-05-31      0
92  2020-06-01      0
93  2020-06-02      1
94  2020-06-03      1
95  2020-06-04      2
96  2020-06-05      3
97  2020-06-06      3
98  2020-06-07      3
99  2020-06-08      3
100 2020-06-09      3
101 2020-06-10      3
102 2020-06-11      3
103 2020-06-12      3
104 2020-06-13      3
105 2020-06-14      3
106 2020-06-15      4
107 2020-06-16      4
108 2020-06-17      4
109 2020-06-18      4
110 2020-06-19      4
111 2020-06-20      4
112 2020-06-21      3
113 2020-06-22      3
114 2020-06-23      3
115 2020-06-24      3
116 2020-06-25      4
117 2020-06-26      7
118 2020-06-27      8
119 2020-06-28      8
120 2020-06-29      8
121 2020-06-30      8
122 2020-07-01     11
123 2020-07-02     12
124 2020-07-03     12
125 2020-07-04     12
126 2020-07-05     11
127 2020-07-06     11
128 2020-07-07     12
129 2020-07-08     13
130 2020-07-09     15
131 2020-07-10     15
132 2020-07-11     15
133 2020-07-12     15
134 2020-07-13     15
135 2020-07-14     15
136 2020-07-15     15
137 2020-07-16     12
138 2020-07-17     10
139 2020-07-18      8
140 2020-07-19      8
141 2020-07-20      8
142 2020-07-21      7
143 2020-07-22      4
144 2020-07-23      4
145 2020-07-24      4
146 2020-07-25      4
147 2020-07-26      4
148 2020-07-27      4
149 2020-07-28      2
150 2020-07-29      2
```

Comment: Just added your solution to my benchmark, your solution is among the most efficient ones!

Answer (score 4):

A solution with base R, no packages required. Function `Counter1` takes a start and end vector of dates.

```
Counter1 <- function(start, end) {
    start <- as.numeric(start)
    end   <- as.numeric(end)
    
    minmax <- range(start, end)
    all.dates <- seq(from = (minmax[1]),
                     to   = (minmax[2]), by = 1)
    count <- numeric(length(all.dates))
    
    for (i in seq_along(start)) {
        d <- seq(from = start[i], to = end[i], by = 1)
        when <- match(d, all.dates)
        count[when] <- count[when] + 1
    }
    data.frame(Date = .Date(all.dates), Count = count)
}
```

Result should be a `data.frame`:

```
Counter1(tempdf$DateStart, tempdf$DateEnd)    
##           Date Count
## 1   2020-03-02     1
## 2   2020-03-03     1
## 3   2020-03-04     1
## 4   2020-03-05     1
## 5   2020-03-06     1
## 6   2020-03-07     1
## 7   2020-03-08     1
## 8   2020-03-09     1
## 9   2020-03-10     1
## 10  2020-03-11     1
## 11  2020-03-12     1
## 12  2020-03-13     1
## 13  2020-03-14     1
## 14  2020-03-15     2
## 15  2020-03-16     2
## ....
```

There is likely room for optimization.

Answer (score 3):

### Base R

*Updated to incorporate @benson23's valuable comments.*

An approach using a *vectorized* `seq`:

```r
f = Vectorize( \(x, y) seq(x, y, by = "day") )

z = 
  with(tempdf, f(x = DateStart, y = DateEnd - 1L)) |> 
  do.call(c, args = _) |> # preserves class
  table() |>
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) |> 
  `colnames<-`(c("Days", "Counts")) |> # cosmetics 
  transform(Days = as.Date(Days)) |>
  merge(data.frame(Days = with(tempdf, seq(min(DateStart), max(DateEnd), "day"))),
        by = "Days", all.y = TRUE)
z[is.na(z)] = 0L
```

results in:

```r
> z
          Days Counts
1   2020-03-02      1
2   2020-03-03      1
3   2020-03-04      1
4   2020-03-05      1
5   2020-03-06      1
6   2020-03-07      1
7   2020-03-08      1
8   2020-03-09      1
9   2020-03-10      1
10  2020-03-11      1
11  2020-03-12      1
12  2020-03-13      1
13  2020-03-14      1
14  2020-03-15      2
15  2020-03-16      2
16  2020-03-17      2
17  2020-03-18      2
18  2020-03-19      2
19  2020-03-20      2
20  2020-03-21      2
21  2020-03-22      2
22  2020-03-23      2
23  2020-03-24      2
24  2020-03-25      2
25  2020-03-26      2
26  2020-03-27      2
27  2020-03-28      1
28  2020-03-29      1
29  2020-03-30      2
30  2020-03-31      2
31  2020-04-01      2
32  2020-04-02      2
33  2020-04-03      2
34  2020-04-04      2
35  2020-04-05      2
36  2020-04-06      2
37  2020-04-07      2
38  2020-04-08      2
39  2020-04-09      1
40  2020-04-10      0
41  2020-04-11      0
42  2020-04-12      0
43  2020-04-13      0
44  2020-04-14      0
45  2020-04-15      0
46  2020-04-16      0
47  2020-04-17      0
48  2020-04-18      0
49  2020-04-19      0
50  2020-04-20      0
51  2020-04-21      0
52  2020-04-22      0
53  2020-04-23      0
54  2020-04-24      0
55  2020-04-25      0
56  2020-04-26      0
57  2020-04-27      0
58  2020-04-28      0
59  2020-04-29      0
60  2020-04-30      0
61  2020-05-01      0
62  2020-05-02      0
63  2020-05-03      0
64  2020-05-04      0
65  2020-05-05      0
66  2020-05-06      0
67  2020-05-07      0
68  2020-05-08      0
69  2020-05-09      0
70  2020-05-10      0
71  2020-05-11      0
72  2020-05-12      0
73  2020-05-13      0
74  2020-05-14      0
75  2020-05-15      0
76  2020-05-16      0
77  2020-05-17      0
78  2020-05-18      0
79  2020-05-19      0
80  2020-05-20      0
81  2020-05-21      0
82  2020-05-22      0
83  2020-05-23      0
84  2020-05-24      0
85  2020-05-25      0
86  2020-05-26      0
87  2020-05-27      0
88  2020-05-28      0
89  2020-05-29      0
90  2020-05-30      0
91  2020-05-31      0
92  2020-06-01      0
93  2020-06-02      1
94  2020-06-03      1
95  2020-06-04      2
96  2020-06-05      3
97  2020-06-06      3
98  2020-06-07      3
99  2020-06-08      3
100 2020-06-09      3
101 2020-06-10      3
102 2020-06-11      3
103 2020-06-12      3
104 2020-06-13      3
105 2020-06-14      3
106 2020-06-15      4
107 2020-06-16      4
108 2020-06-17      4
109 2020-06-18      4
110 2020-06-19      4
111 2020-06-20      3
112 2020-06-21      3
113 2020-06-22      3
114 2020-06-23      3
115 2020-06-24      3
116 2020-06-25      4
117 2020-06-26      7
118 2020-06-27      8
119 2020-06-28      8
120 2020-06-29      8
121 2020-06-30      8
122 2020-07-01     11
123 2020-07-02     12
124 2020-07-03     12
125 2020-07-04     11
126 2020-07-05     11
127 2020-07-06     11
128 2020-07-07     12
129 2020-07-08     13
130 2020-07-09     15
131 2020-07-10     15
132 2020-07-11     15
133 2020-07-12     15
134 2020-07-13     15
135 2020-07-14     15
136 2020-07-15     12
137 2020-07-16     10
138 2020-07-17      8
139 2020-07-18      8
140 2020-07-19      8
141 2020-07-20      7
142 2020-07-21      4
143 2020-07-22      4
144 2020-07-23      4
145 2020-07-24      4
146 2020-07-25      4
147 2020-07-26      4
148 2020-07-27      2
149 2020-07-28      2
150 2020-07-29      0
```

If this isn't fast enough, chances are we can replace `table()` and the inefficient `Date`-conversion.

---

Data:

```r
tempdf = structure(list(
  DateStart = structure(c(18323, 18351, 18336, 18415, 18417, 18418, 18428, 18439, 18439, 18438, 
                          18440, 18439, 18444, 18451, 18444, 18452, 18444, 18445, 18450, 18452), 
                        tzone = "Asia/Manila", class = "Date"), 
  DateEnd = structure(c(18362, 18361, 18349, 18433, 18470, 18460, 18447, 18460, 18458, 18458, 18459, 
                        18459, 18472, 18463, 18464, 18464, 18458, 18464, 18472, 18470), 
                      tzone = "Asia/Manila", class = "Date"), 
  Length = structure(c(39, 10, 13, 18, 53, 42, 19, 21, 19, 20, 19, 20, 28, 12, 20, 12, 14, 19, 22, 18),
                     class = "difftime", units = "days")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need for loop for this. With `lapply`, we can create date sequences more efficiently than for loop.

```r
library(dplyr)

date_name <- seq.Date(min(tempdf$DateStart), max(tempdf$DateEnd), 1)
date_combine <- c(as.Date(unlist(lapply(1:nrow(tempdf), \(x) seq.Date(tempdf[x, 1, drop = T], tempdf[x, 2, drop = T] - 1, 1)))), date_name)
date_count <- c(table(date_combine) - 1)
tibble(Days = as.Date(names(date_count)), Counts = unname(date_count))

# A tibble: 150 × 2
   Days       Counts
   <date>      <dbl>
 1 2020-03-02      1
 2 2020-03-03      1
 3 2020-03-04      1
 4 2020-03-05      1
 5 2020-03-06      1
 6 2020-03-07      1
 7 2020-03-08      1
 8 2020-03-09      1
 9 2020-03-10      1
10 2020-03-11      1
# ℹ 140 more rows
```

#### Benchmarking

Seems like @EnricoSchumann and @ThomasIsCoding solutions are the most efficient so far (results are not checked due to the issue of inclusive/exclusive date range).

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(OP = {
  Days=createDays(min(tempdf$DateStart),
                  max(tempdf$DateEnd))
  Counts=CaseCountGenerator(tempdf$DateStart,
                            tempdf$DateEnd,
                           tempdf$Length,
                            Days)
  result=tibble(Days,Counts)
  },
  benson23 = {
    date_name <- seq.Date(min(tempdf$DateStart), max(tempdf$DateEnd), 1)
    date_count <- c(table(c(as.Date(unlist(lapply(1:nrow(tempdf), \(x) seq.Date(tempdf[x, 1, drop = T], tempdf[x, 2, drop = T] - 1, 1)))), date_name)) - 1)
    tibble(Days = as.Date(names(date_count)), Counts = unname(date_count))
  }, 
  Friede = {
    f = Vectorize( \(x, y) seq(x, y, by = "day") )
    z = 
      with(tempdf, f(x = DateStart, y = DateEnd - 1)) |> 
      do.call(c, args = _) |> # preserves class
      table() |>
      as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) |> # cosmetics
      `colnames<-`(c("Days", "Counts")) |> # cosmetics 
      transform(Days = as.Date(Days)) |>
      merge(data.frame(Days = with(tempdf, seq(min(DateStart), max(DateEnd), "day"))),                                         
            by = "Days", all = TRUE)
    z[is.na(z)] = 0L
    as_tibble(z)
  },
  Onyambu = {
    tempdf %>%
      reframe(Days = do.call(c, map2(DateStart, DateEnd, ~seq(.x, .y, 'day'))))%>%
      mutate(Days = factor(Days, seq(min(Days), max(Days), 'day'))) %>%
      count(Days, name = "Count", .drop = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(Days = as.Date(Days))
  },
  Enrico = {
    Counter1 <- function(start, end) {
      start <- as.numeric(start)
      end   <- as.numeric(end)
      
      minmax <- range(start, end)
      all.dates <- seq(from = (minmax[1]),
                       to   = (minmax[2]), by = 1)
      count <- numeric(length(all.dates))
      
      for (i in seq_along(start)) {
        d <- seq(from = start[i], to = end[i], by = 1)
        when <- match(d, all.dates)
        count[when] <- count[when] + 1
      }
      data.frame(Date = .Date(all.dates), Count = count)
    }
    as_tibble(Counter1(tempdf$DateStart, tempdf$DateEnd))
  },
  Thomas = {
    with(tempdf, {
      d <- seq(min(DateStart), max(DateEnd), by = "day")
      cnt <- rowSums(outer(d, DateStart, `>=`) & outer(d, DateEnd, `<=`))
      tibble(date = d, counts = cnt)
    })
  })

Unit: microseconds
     expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval  cld
       OP 32179.601 33505.4505 35779.7510 34330.1515 38170.2005 51278.601   100 a   
 benson23  3307.800  3389.6505  3689.7650  3482.4515  3603.7005  8645.601   100  b  
   Friede  3236.602  3339.6010  3548.1880  3435.3010  3564.1510  8368.901   100  b  
  Onyambu  5920.502  6204.4015  6675.9750  6496.4515  6639.3510 12249.000   100   c 
   Enrico   407.801   448.7010   541.7940   471.9015   499.0505  5729.300   100    d
   Thomas   446.900   498.3005   528.6131   517.5010   540.2010   705.601   100    d
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate the benchmark on all the answers as it also helps me decide which to accept. I'm not yet an expert on it so I'm very glad. "+1"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

tempdf %>%
  reframe(Date = do.call(c, map2(DateStart, DateEnd, ~seq(.x,.y, 'day'))))%>%
  mutate(Date = factor(Date, seq(min(Date), max(Date), 'day'))) %>%
  count(Date, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
```

Comment: @benson23 thanks for pointing that out. the edit should solve OP's issue now

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>% 
  reframe(days = map2(DateStart, DateEnd, ~ seq(.x, .y, by = 1))) %>% 
  unnest(days) %>% 
  count(days) %>% 
  complete(days = full_seq(days, 1), fill = list(n = 0)) 

# A tibble: 111 × 2
   days           n
   <date>     <int>
 1 2020-03-02     1
 2 2020-03-03     1
 3 2020-03-04     1
 4 2020-03-05     1
 5 2020-03-06     1
 6 2020-03-07     1
 7 2020-03-08     1
 8 2020-03-09     1
 9 2020-03-10     1
10 2020-03-11     1
# ℹ 101 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple with timeplyr's vectorised `time_seq_v()`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(timeplyr)

tibble(date = time_seq_v(
  tempdf$DateStart, 
  tempdf$DateEnd, 
  "days"
)) %>%
  count(date)
#> # A tibble: 98 × 2
#>    date           n
#>    <date>     <int>
#>  1 2020-03-02     1
#>  2 2020-03-03     1
#>  3 2020-03-04     1
#>  4 2020-03-05     1
#>  5 2020-03-06     1
#>  6 2020-03-07     1
#>  7 2020-03-08     1
#>  8 2020-03-09     1
#>  9 2020-03-10     1
#> 10 2020-03-11     1
#> # ℹ 88 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Package "IRanges" is suitable for these tasks. First define the data as an IRanges object:

```
library(IRanges)
rngs = IRanges(start = as.numeric(tempdf$DateStart), end = as.numeric(tempdf$DateEnd))
```

And a lookup IRanges object of the days sequence:

```
days.seq = seq(do.call(min, tempdf[1:2]), do.call(max, tempdf[1:2]), by = "1 day")
days = IRanges(start = as.numeric(days.seq), end = as.numeric(days.seq))
```

Finally count the overlaps:

```
frequencies = countOverlaps(days, rngs)
data.frame(day = days.seq, frequency = frequencies)
```